# a problem with heredocs syntax?

Tags: php, html, image, heredoc

I have a problem with the syntax for a heredoc. Let me show the code first:

```
    function format($user_id,$user_note,$image,$dt){

        //this is the problem
      if($image=='NULL'){
     //don't display image
     }

     else {
  echo '<img src="userpics/$image" width="480" height="480">';
}
         return <<<ENDOFRETURN
       <div class ="commentbox">
                         $date
                         </div>
                             <div class="leftpanel">

                           $user_note
                        $image
                                 <div class="date">
                                    $rel
                                 </div>
                             </div>
    ENDOFRETURN;

}
```

The `$image` variable comes from the database, it's either NULL or has a filename. If an image is null I don't want to display the `<img>` tag, if it does have a value then I want to show it. Do you know how I can solve this problem? I have been trying everything, but nothing has worked yet!! :))

Comment: sorry, I don't get your code you print and return in the same function? and you need qoutes for your echo ` echo '<img src="userpics/$image" width="480" height="480">'; `

Comment: loool i dnt understand my code aswell!!! :)) yeh i have chnaged it sorry!!!

Comment: **your main problem is heredoc itself**. never use it to output HTML. PHP has way more reliable ways to do it

Comment: can you give me an example please @col

Comment: I still don't get what your actual problem is (besides the errors in the code). What is happening and what should happen?

Comment: @felix basically, i want to show an image if it exists which is from $image, or if $image is NULL then dnt display the image!! :)) $image is either `NULL` or `1235.jpg`

Comment: @getaway: But you already have `echo '<img src="userpics/$image" width="480" height="480">';` in your code which should work.

Comment: it deos work, but if the $image is NULL , in the page source it shows up as `<img src="userpics/NULL".....` that deos not look good in safari trust me!!!

Comment: @getaway that's because the variable is actually `NULL`, **not** the *string* `'NULL'`. `'NULL' !== NULL`

Comment: I need to know context. Where does that returned HTML go?

Comment: What is `$rel` and `$dt` and what do they contain? Where does `$rel` come from? Cause it isn't defined in the scope of this function. Why are you '`echo`'ing `$image` near the `$user_note` output? Why do you pass `$user_id` when you don't use it? You should reconsider every aspect of this function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If data in a MySQL database is `NULL`, you would check that with the `is_null()` function, not comparing to the string `'NULL'`:

```
function format($user_id,$user_note,$image,$dt)
{
  if(!is_null($image)){
     $image = "<img src=\"userpics/$image\" width=\"480\" height=\"480\">";
  }
  return <<<ENDOFRETURN
   <div class ="commentbox">$date</div>
   <div class="leftpanel">
     $user_note
     $image
     <div class="date">$rel</div>
   </div>
ENDOFRETURN;
}
```

Also, as others have mentioned, the end of the heredoc must **not** be indented.

**EDIT:** I just edited a few other things in your code and showed the whole function to give you a better idea.

Comment: thanks for the answer, yeh but how could i show the $image then!! its more complex when your dealing heredocs syntax

Comment: @getaway: As others have mentioned, make sure the `ENDOFRETURN;` is not indented.

Comment: @getaway: I just edited a few other things in your code and showed the whole function to better indicate what I'm trying to say.

Comment: thanks i love the clean loook!!! but it still desont work!!!! it wnt show the images at all!!! now

Comment: @getaway: Sorry, silly mistake in my code, see edits. I needed to be using `"` not `'`

Comment: @josh your a genious i owe you one thanks +1 upvote from me!!! sorry for the messy code, im a bit clumsy, i will have to pay for it later though!!!

Comment: @getaway: Haha, thank you :-) I'm glad I could help. If you don't understand *why* my code works and yours doesn't please just ask, I'll be happy to explain further.

Comment: @josh thanks mate, is it okay if i have tha values in my database as just empty rather than NULL, or would that cause a problem!!

Comment: @getaway: That's fine, and might be easier to understand. If you store it that way, change `if(!is_null(` to `if(!is_empty(`

Comment: @josh thanks yeh i have thanks, its so much better to deal with empty, im used to it, cheers anmway!!!

Comment: That's the reason I said it *might* be easier to understand. `NULL` is powerful and has it's place, but, adds an additional layer which can sometimes confuse. If you don't need to distinguish between empty and `NULL`, just use an empty string. Remember to update your database and may that column `NOT NULL` :-)

Answer (score 4):

I can see several problems with your code, but where the heredocs syntax is concerned, try removing the spaces before `ENDOFRETURN;`.

Comment: @getaway: Then what specifically is the problem you're seeing?

Comment: thiers no problem, but i dnt want to it to show the image if its NULL, the img src or otherwise this will show up `<img src="userpics/NULL".....`

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems, the correct way would be something like:

```
function format($user_id,$user_note,$image,$dt){

    //this is the problem
    if($image !== NULL){
        $output .= '<img src="userpics/' . $image . '" width="480" height="480">';
    }
    $output .= <<<ENDOFRETURN
    <div class ="commentbox">
                     $date
                     </div>
                         <div class="leftpanel">

                       $user_note
                    $image
                             <div class="date">
                                $rel
                             </div>
                         </div>
ENDOFRETURN;

    return $output;
}
```

you see:

- `ENDOFRETURN;` has no spaces before it
- all output is returned in one ... return

Comment: I think what you're failing to note for the OP is that instead of checking if `$image` is equal to the string `"NULL"` you're actually checking if it is not equal to the uninitialized constant `NULL`. If it is not equal to that constant, then it is added to the `$output` string. Which is then returned at the end of the function. Aside from that, the OP's original function has _many_ problems and probably ought to be split into at least two different functions.

Comment: @sholsinger as he said "it's either NULL or has a filename" so thats completely valid

Comment: No I agree it is valid. I'm saying that I believe it needs to be explained more fully for the OP.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of being thorough:

`NULL` is a keyword, just like: `print`, `echo`, `if`, `for`. Meanwhile,'NULL' (note the quotes) is a string, just like if you had typed 'if' (note the quotes, again) it would be a string, not the beginning of an `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

simply adjust

```
{spaces or tab}ENDOFRETURN;
```

to

```
{no spaces/tab}ENDOFRETURN;
```

[rtm - exactly same problem as yours](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

> It is very important to note that the line with the closing identifier must contain no other characters, except possibly a semicolon (;). That means especially that the identifier may not be indented, and there may not be any spaces or tabs before or after the semicolon. It's also important to realize that the first character before the closing identifier must be a newline as defined by the local operating system. This is \n on UNIX systems, including Mac OS X. The closing delimiter (possibly followed by a semicolon) must also be followed by a newline.
>
> If this rule is broken and the closing identifier is not "clean", it will not be considered a closing identifier, and PHP will continue looking for one. If a proper closing identifier is not found before the end of the current file, a parse error will result at the last line.

Comment: huh i dnt get it!! what do u mean :))

Comment: yeh i know on my real code it s like that, it deos show here!! but thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your echo statement in single quotes as above, won't do what you intend it to.  The variable $image will not be expanded in a single-quoted string.  Reverse your single and double quoting instead as

```
echo "<img src='userpics/$image' width='480' height='480'>";
```

Also the ENDOFRETURN; at closing your heredoc must not have any spaces before it.